# Auto-Complete Pardot Form

Tags: integration, pardot

We have a subsidiary company on their own instance of SFDC and they use Pardot.  We want to be able to send information to them via a Pardot webpage.  For example, when we save a record in our instance of SFDC it would trigger a workflow of some sort to then complete a form in their Pardot webpage.  Does anyone know if this is even possible and if so where I can find documentation on how to accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options:

1. Use a Pardot form handler and do a server side post submission in a apex trigger or JS button. Ensure that you enable kiosk mode.
2. Use Pardot API within an apex trigger to create a prospect.

In my view the first option is the most simplistic.